# Change Password Class and SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I make a function to  change password for my user.
I still havent create a XML for the button and field for the change password, give me an idea on how to do it and I will do my research.

Heres my database

LogInDataBase

```
package com.example.androidxxx;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter {
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + "LOGIN" + "( "
            + "ID" + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text); ";
    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context context;
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

    public LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,
                DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance() {
        return db;
    }

    public void insertEntry(String userName, String password) {
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        newValues.put("PASSWORD", password);
        db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);

    }

    public int deleteEntry(String UserName) {

        String where = "USERNAME=?";
        int numberOFEntriesDeleted = db.delete("LOGIN", where,
                new String[] { UserName });
        return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
    }

    public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName) {
        Cursor cursor = db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?",
                new String[] { userName }, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;
    }

    public void updateEntry(String userName, String password) {
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
        updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        updatedValues.put("PASSWORD", password);

        String where = "USERNAME = ?";
        db.update("LOGIN", updatedValues, where, new String[] { userName });
    }
}
```

my Main Activity

```
package com.example.androidxxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnSignInStudent, btnSignInFaculty, btnSignInAdmin;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

        btnSignInStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignINStudent);
        btnSignInFaculty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignINFaculty);
        btnSignInAdmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignINAdmin);

    }

    public void signInStudent(View V1) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
        dialog.setTitle("Login");
        final EditText editTextUserName = (EditText) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
        final EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

        Button btnSignInStudent = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

        btnSignInStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v1) {

                String userName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter
                        .getSinlgeEntry(userName);
                if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent main = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(main);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "User Name or Password does not match",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }


    public void signInFaculty(View V2) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
        dialog.setTitle("Login");
        final EditText editTextUserName = (EditText) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
        final EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

        Button btnSignInFaculty = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

        btnSignInFaculty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v2) {

                String userName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter
                        .getSinlgeEntry(userName);
                if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent main = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(main);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "User Name or Password does not match",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }
}
```